# Bundle Quasar/Express/Electron App for production - Express-server doesn't start

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I'm building an app and all works fine while I'm in developer mode. Everythink works as it should. But when I package my app, the app opens but it doesnt start express server.

For development-testing I run in bash the **command “node server.js”**. Now I don’t know the correct settings in quasar.conf.js or package.json to
a) start the localhost server on app start and
b) close the localhost when the app is closed and shut down

One thing I read is that I could install shelljs and start the backend server in the e.g. the electron-main.js file with the same command node server.js.
I also found a thread describing a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436594/electron-build-app-doesnt-start-express-server), but I have no “build” settings yet and am unsure whether to change anything in “quasar.conf.js” in electron-packager or builder or something in package.json

I’d be happy for any hint, what setting works and preferably also shuts the server down when the app is closed.

Also is there a good resource to find necessary settings and other things that must be respected when switching from development to production with quasar/express/electron?

EDIT:
I found this potentially valuable [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533056/how-to-package-express-server-inside-electron-app). I think background.ts now translates to my electron-main.js file, I can't get it right yet.

Cheers Chris

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "Quasar app",
  "author": "c",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^2.0.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^9.3.1",
    "electron-debug": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.18.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

**quasar.conf.js**

```
  module.exports = function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    boot: [
      'axios',
    ],

    css: [
      'app.sass'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', 
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        })
      },
    },

    devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 8080,
      open: true
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      lang: 'en-us', // Quasar language pack
      config: {},

     

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: ['LocalStorage', 'jquery']
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW
      manifest: {
        name: `Quasar App`,
        short_name: `Quasar App`,
        description: `A Quasar Framework app`,
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: []
      }
    },

    cordova: {

    },

    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {

      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'vuextest'
      },

      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: true,

      extendWebpack (/* cfg */) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the start script in `package.json`, for example

```
...
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
...
```

`npm start` is the ussual way how node.js apps are started and it is starting the task `start` in scripts section. More can be found [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/an-introduction-to-the-npm-package-manager#running-tasks)

I am not sure about shotdown, but when the flow of the code finishes its execution and is not waiting for interaction or anything, it should shutdown the whole node.js app.

Comment: Hi Zavael, thank you for your input. I tried this, but it didn't change anything. Do you have another idea as a start script or similar?
I previously found that with shelljs I could call it from the code but still in the command. Do you know where I could place this?

Comment: I am not sure about shelljs, maybe I would start with a simple node.js + express helloworld app and deploy it to see if that works